# Set a variable to be another variable with a number + or -

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a program in batch. It has to take a variable which is a number and add or subtract from that variable to get another number.

I currently have:

```
set /A str="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3
set /A dex="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3
set /A con="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3
set /A int="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3
set /A wis="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3
set /A cha="%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+1+"%RANDOM% %% 6"+3 

set /a Data11="%str% %% 1"+2
set /a Data12=%dex%
set /a Data13="%con% %% 1"+2
set /a Data14="%int% %% 1"-2
set /a Data15=%wis%
set /a Data16=%cha%
```

Unfortunately it is currently setting the Data11, 13, and 14 to just the +2 or -2.

I want it to work this way so I can have many different sets of alterations to preform on the str, dex, ectra variables which in turn depend on user input and choice.

How can I get it to work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

you set Data11 variables to be `str modulus 1` which is 0

Comment: if you want 0 or 1, you have to modulo with 2 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes for most arithmetic or percent signs on normal variables
 - and I removed the `%% 1` for this example.

```
set /A str=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3
set /A dex=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3
set /A con=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3
set /A int=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3
set /A wis=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3
set /A cha=%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+1+%RANDOM% %% 6+3 

set /a Data11=str + 2
set /a Data12=dex
set /a Data13=con + 2
set /a Data14=int - 2
set /a Data15=wis
set /a Data16=cha

set data
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following are also valid:

```
SET/A Data11="str %% 2 + 2"
SET/A "Data11=str %% 2 + 2"
SET/A Data12=dex

SET/A temp=dex+1
```

More information and examples:

[Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx)

[SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)